# Show unity 3D in xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a question. Is it possible to load unity project from web, and show it in Xcode project? In some non-fullscreen view? Also, unity must handle touch events. Any ideas, suggestions, links or anything else?
Thanks for advice.
P.S. Sorry for my english.
P.P.S. Main project created in Xcode, without unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> load unity project from web

What do you mean by that? If you mean a compiled unity [webplayer](http://unity3d.com/webplayer/) application, forget it.
If you mean a standard non compiled Unity project, note that with the [iOS plugin](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/mobile) you can compile for mobile Apple hardware. This used to cost a lot of money but now they're [giving it out for free](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/05/21/putting-the-power-of-unity-in-the-hands-of-every-mobile-developer/) (included in Unity free).

> Also, unity must handle touch events.

The standard `Input` Unity class handles touch events with methods such as [GetTouch()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) and variables like [touchCount](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html) or [touches](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html).

---

Unity is a very big and complex package: integrating it into an existing project may be overwhelmingly difficult. I really don't think there are natives way to do so.
Rather, I'd advise you to port your current XCode project into Unity (which sounds a really strange thing to do if you ask me).

Unity and XCode are 2 completely different tools: the former is useful for Cocoa classes and iOS IDE while the latter is for managing 3d game assets in a real-time interactive environment. I don't see how you can possibly integrate the two things.

Manage your project in a single IDE, it will make things a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank You for answer. After continues search, I realized that it is. No way to integrate Unity in Xcode project, but integrate Xcode project in Unity possible.